# dynamically adjusting data structure

Tags: hash

why do we dynamically adjust the hash table size based on load factor only? 
Is there any possible implications we may have if we choose to increase the table size geometrically whenever a collision is detected in a uniform distribution hashing strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Load factor is roughly the probability of collision assuming the hash function is good, so the two ideas are not far apart.

Load factor is used because it's easy to compute, and it's not statistically noisy, which actual collisions are.

An additional reason is the cost of traversing all elements in the table.  An empty bucket still has to be checked, so a bracket on load factor is also a bracket on the worst possible performance of enumerating all stored elements.

The natural noise in collision patterns is a problem when using them to adjust table size. We would never want to follow exactly the policy you propose.  Even with a load factor of 25%, we'd gemetrically grow (say by factor G>1) the table on each insertion with probability 1/4, then again with probability 1/(4G), etc.  And how would we decide when to shrink a table?  Certainly not each time there is no collision!

So in fact we'd have to count collisions vs. insertions in a "window" and adjust when the ratio exceeds high and low thresholds. The window would have to be fairly large to filter out noise with good probability. It would require storage and computing overhead to maintain. This is probably not worthwhile, at least for the small tables used most of the time.

Still, in settings like databases where tables are big and there are many operations, actual stats are used to optimize performance. I'm not sure if hash table size is included in this optimization in real software, but it's possible.  The most likely reason I can imagine would be unwillingness to accept the tiny risk that the hash function will fail.

Comment: we do not need to count the collisions. we are assuming that we have uniform hashing function and on the very first collision we increase the table size to double. i think this strategy is by no way less effecient than the strategy based on load factor.

Comment: in this way, it will no longer be statistically noisy as well.